# How can I read the attributes of a root node without getting them by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

Suppose, I have the follwing XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library attrib1="att11" attrib2="att22">
    library-text
    <book isbn="1111111111">
        <title lang="en">T1 T1 T1 T1 T1</title>
        <date>2001</date>
        <author>A1 A1 A1 A1 A1</author>     
        <price>10.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="2222222222">
        <title lang="en">T2 T2 T2 T2 T2</title>
        <date>2002</date>
        <author>A2 A2 A2 A2 A2</author>     
        <price>20.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="3333333333">
        <title lang="en">T3 T3 T3 T3</title>
        <date>2003</date>
        <author>A3 A3 A3 A3 A3y</author>        
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</library>
```

I want to programmatically print the names of the attributes and their values of the root-node.

How can I do that?

I tried the following code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

xml_fname = "library.xml"

dom = minidom.parse(xml_fname) 

print(dom.firstChild.tagName)
print(dom.firstChild.attributes[0].value)
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(dom.firstChild.attributes[0].value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you use lxml?

Comment: @JackFleeting, No. I am not allowed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM `Node.attributes` object is a [`NamedNodeMap` object](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1780488922), you'll have to use the interface defined in the specification. You can't just index into them, there is no support for Python-like indexing.

The specification tells you there is a `.length` attribute, and an `item()` method which returns a Node subtype, here those are [`Attr` objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-637646024):

```
>>> attributes = dom.firstChild.attributes
>>> for i in range(attributes.length):
...     print(attributes.item(i))
...
<xml.dom.minidom.Attr object at 0x10e47f6d0>
<xml.dom.minidom.Attr object at 0x10e47f660>
```

Each of those `Attr` objects have `name` and `value` attributes:

```
>>> for i in range(attributes.length):
...     attr = attributes.item(i)
...     print(f"Name: {attr.name}, value: {attr.value}")
...
Name: attrib1, value: att11
Name: attrib2, value: att22
```

I've said this in my previous answer, but I'll reiterate it here: The DOM API is *extremely bare bones*, and not at all Pythonic. It does not behave like you'd expect Python objects to behave. Use the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) if you want something more Pythonic. The ElementTree API elements have an `.attrib` attribute that's a Python dictionary, for example.